# Omitting Unary Constructors

Tags: haskell

I am writing some code to express "expressions" built from members of a given type:

```
data Expr a = Simply a | Add (Expr a, Expr a) | Mult (Expr a, Expr a)
```

One can define some infix operators to make it more convenient to construct these:

```
(+++) :: Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr a
x +++ y = Add (x, y)

(***) :: Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr a
x *** y = Mult (x, y)
```

Hence one can just write

```
(Simply "bar") +++ ((Simply "fo") *** (Simply "o"))
```

to get

```
Add (Simply "bar",Mult (Simply "fo",Simply "o"))
```

Now the question is if there is a way to omit the constructor `Simply` as well, i.e. to consider any member of the type `a` implicitly as a member of `Expr a` and obtain the example above directly from `("bar") +++ (("fo") *** ("o"))`.

Comment: That's not a type constructor, it's just a constructor.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can make a typeclass of expressions like this:

```
class IsExpr a b | a -> b where 
      ex :: a -> Expr b
```

This defines a class of types a which are expressions of types b, where b is declared to be determined by a using a functional dependency.

Then you go ahead and make `String` into an expression of type `Expr String`:

```
instance IsExpr String String where
     ex = Simply
```

Furthermore, somewhat unsurprisingly, expressions are also expressions:

```
instance IsExpr (Expr a) a where
     ex = id
```

Now you can redefine your operators so that they can take any combination of things which yield expressions of the same type, i.e. any argument can be a `String` or an `Expr String` or whatever you define `IsExpr` instances for:

```
(++++) :: (IsExpr a c, IsExpr b c) => a -> b -> Expr c
x ++++ y = Add (ex x, ex y)

(****) :: (IsExpr a c, IsExpr b c) => a -> b -> Expr c
x **** y = Mult (ex x, ex y)
```

This does need some extensions though: `TypeSynonymInstances` (only if you use `String`s), `FlexibleInstances`, `MultiParamTypeClasses` and `FunctionalDependencies`. Of course there is a complexity/benefit tradeoff, so maybe the benefit isn't worth the additional complexity.

BTW, I'd rather define the data constructors as `Add (Expr a) (Expr a)`. You are adding an
 additional indirection by using a tuple.

Answer (score 3):

You can remove the `Simply` constructor using the `-XOverloadedStrings` extension.

```
 {-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings, FlexibleInstances #-}
 import Data.String

 instance IsString (Expr String) where
   fromString = Simply
```

And then create a `Num` instance to get normal operators

```
 instance Num (Expr a) where
  (+) = curry Add
  (*) = curry Mult
```

And then you can do things like

```
"foo" + "bar" + "baz" :: Expr String
```

All this does is cause GHC to interpret `"..."`'s as `fromString "..."`.

Comment: This solution only works for Strings. Since `Expr` has a type parameter, it will presumably be used with something other than a String.

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on using mathematical operators on Strings, you can <strike>make `Expr a` an instance of the `Num` class:</strike> make a new typeclass with those operations:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

class ExprOps a where
   type Internal a
   (+++) :: a -> a -> a
   (***) :: a -> a -> a
   fromInternal :: Internal a -> a

instance ExprOps (Expr a) where
  type Internal (Expr a) = a
  x +++ y = Add (x,y)
  x *** y = Mult (x,y)
  fromInternal = Simply
```

Then you can simply write

```
foo :: Expr String
foo = "bar" +++ "fo" *** "o"
```

which still results in the expression

```
Add (Simply "bar",Mult (Simply "fo",Simply "o"))
```

but does not require any explicit `Simply` constructors.

Comment: That doesn't work, `fromInteger :: Integer -> a`, not `String -> a`